# Converting Multiple Polygons to Raster and ASCII

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r

I've 27084 polygons representing protected areas. I need to convert to raster (where the protected area will be value 1 and the wider landscape 0), then convert the rasters to ASCII. all of which need the same extent.

Any ideas how to do this other than individually converting each one?

I've access to ArcMap 10.5 and R.

Comment: Do you really need each protected area to be its own ascii raster, instead of a single raster that shows where all protected areas are?

Comment: I'm afraid they need to be separate ASCII files as they are meant to represent different starting distributions of a species.

Comment: I've updated my answer with thorough, step-by-step details of how to do this without using Python or ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps easier than using Python or ModelBuilder, you can simply take advantage of the [Batch option in ArcToolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm).

1. In ArcToolbox, navigate to *Data Management Tools > Fields > [Add Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm)*
2. Right-click on *Add Field* and then select *Batch*
3. In ArcCatalog, navigate to the directory that contains your feature classes, select all them and then drag them into the *AddField* dialog.
4. In the top row, under *Field Name*, enter a field name (let's say, 'Occupancy')
5. Right-click on the field name, and then select *Fill*. This will populate all the rows with the same value.
6. In the top row, under *Field Type*, select "SHORT", and then right-click > *Fill*.
7. Click *OK*, and then all your feature classes will have a new Short Integer field named Occupancy.
8. Once again, in *ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Fields*, right-click on *[Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm)* and select *Batch*.
9. Once again, drag and drop all your feature classes to the tool dialog.
10. In the first row, under *Field Name*, select "Occupancy", then right-click > *Fill*
11. In the first row, under *Expression*, enter *1*, then right-click > *Fill*.
12. Click *OK* to run, and now all of your feature classes will have their new field populated with a value of 1.
13. Navigate to *ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Raster*, right-click on *[Polygon to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm)* and then select *Batch*.
14. Drag and drop all your feature classes onto the tool dialog
15. In the top row, under *Value Field*, select "Occupancy" (or whatever you named your new field), and then right-click > *Fill*
16. Be sure that your raster settings (e.g., cell size, cell assignment, snapping) are set as needed in both the tool and in the *Environments* (see the bottom of the tool dialog).
17. Click the [Check Values button](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm#GUID-026012F7-0F06-4078-8529-881C9941F542), to populate the output raster paths.
18. Click *OK* to run, and then you'll have all your rasters.
19. Since you need them in ASCII (I don't think you can convert directly from polygon to ASCII...), follow the same pattern as in the previous steps, but using the tool *ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > From Raster > Raster to ASCII*.

If you really need the background to be 0 instead of NoData, then you can run a [Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) where the raster [IsNull](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/is-null.htm). See: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010059

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model with an iterator to do the same in each feature. Find more info here:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm

Remember to create a geodatabase because is the imput for the iterator.